# Testing ReCaptcha Dynamically?

Tags: php, ajax, captcha, recaptcha

I've got recaptcha working in it's fundamental form - requiring a captcha code and displaying a basic error when it's wrong. But I want to make it more usable, and I'd really appreciate your help.

Is there any way to ajaxically send a test/request to see if the captcha code is correct, and if it's not, pre-emptively prompt the user for another attempt?

Failing that possibility - is there any way to ensure that all the fields keep their values if I were to php redirect the user back to the form page?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check in js that user has checked the checkbox in Google recaptcha?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28674946/how-to-check-in-js-that-user-has-checked-the-checkbox-in-google-recaptcha)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reCAPTCHA has an AJAX API [as described here](http://recaptcha.net/apidocs/captcha/client.html#ajaxapi).

You need to include the script in your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.recaptcha.net/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"></script>
```

And then define a callback to fire when it gets the response:

```
Recaptcha.create("6LdIEwAA......",
  "recaptcha_div", {
  theme: "red",
  callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
});
```

There's a demo of it working [here](http://recaptcha.net/fastcgi/demo/ajax).

Comment: Unfortunately, both of your links are returning error 404 not found. Good thing you provided the actual content in your answer, as it retains value despite the broken links!