# How to check in js that user has checked the checkbox in Google recaptcha?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, recaptcha

I have added the following before end of head

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

I have added this before end of form

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="== xxxxxx =="></div>
```

I can see the recaptcha similar to https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/

HOwever, when user presses data without checking the checkbox, the data is submitted. Is there any other code I need to add to check if user has pressed the checkbox? Hopefully in js?

Comment: did you read this page: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

Comment: yeep.. cant seem to figure out how to get this working though

Comment: you should request that on your backend server. it wouldn't be very safe for the browser to do it alone.

Comment: That is fine. How to request that from front end maybe using jquery?

Answer (score 205, accepted):

Google has a call back option for when the checkbox is checked.

Add this to your form element:

```
data-callback="XXX"
```

Example:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="recaptchaCallback" data-sitekey="== xxxxxx =="></div>
```

And a disable attribute to your submit button.

Example:

```
<button id="submitBtn" disabled>Submit</button>
```

Then a create a callback function and write whatever code you need.

Example:

```
function recaptchaCallback() {
    $('#submitBtn').removeAttr('disabled');
};
```

Comment: will that be working if the page has two captcha codes ?

Comment: Possibly, you would need to add in extra functionality to check if both callbacks where called before enabling the submit button.

Comment: The point of having captcha is to avoid scripted access(Bot), But using like this will provide no benefits since it can be bypassed by executing `$('#submitBtn').removeAttr('disabled');`  in the scripts.

Comment: @mohanenb: It's just to prevent sending, it's not meant not to check server side like usual.

Comment: How to tackle timeout problem ? If someone checks the reCaptcha and then don't submit form for few minutes then reCaptcha will expire but user still able to submit the form ..!

Comment: @AkshayKapoor [data-expired-callback](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display)

Comment: Just a heads up to place the function recaptchaCallback() outside of document.ready so that it can be reachable by the captcha control.  Otherwise, you'll receive a console.log error like "ReCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function:".

Comment: This solution merely calls a function when the captcha _is_ solved, but does not provide a function to check whether the captcha _was_ solved.

Comment: The second answer by Olafur should be the accepted answer.  For 2 reasons.  1) It's a lot more work.  2) Handling expired validations...

Comment: Validating captcha on client side is a bad idea. Anyone can easily call your callback from the console.

Comment: you of course have to validate the captcha on the server side too. you can't reply in client side validation only.

Answer (score 82):

You can also call the grecaptcha object to check. `grecaptcha.getResponse();` is empty when unchecked and has the verification code when checked.

`grecaptcha.getResponse().length === 0`  when unchecked

```
function isCaptchaChecked() {
  return grecaptcha && grecaptcha.getResponse().length !== 0;
}

if (isCaptchaChecked()) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: But, how to get grecaptcha.getResponse()?

Comment: It's loaded as soon as you load google's recaptcha. Part of the package

Comment: i tried but not working, console debug says>>  " Uncaught ReferenceError: grecaptcha is not defined"

Comment: script should load recaptcha first, try to do it async or with setTimeout

Comment: `var isCaptchaChecked = (grecaptcha && grecaptcha.getResponse().length !== 0);`

Comment: This indeed answers the OP question. The chosen answer merely calls a function when the captcha _is_ solved, but does not provide a function to check whether the captcha _was_ solved.

Comment: If your grecaptcha is undefined, make sure your explicitly render your recapcha like so `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadRender&render=explicit`, more info see: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#explicitly_render_the_recaptcha_widget

Answer (score 14):

To check if **google recaptcha** is checked or not you can do it by the following code :

```
<script>

if(grecaptcha && grecaptcha.getResponse().length > 0)
{
     //the recaptcha is checked
     // Do what you want here
     alert('Well, recaptcha is checked !');
}
else
{
    //The recaptcha is not cheched
    //You can display an error message here
    alert('Oops, you have to check the recaptcha !');
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Let the browser do the job for you! (based on slinky2000 answer)

**note:** this is only to prevent sending an 'accidentally' unchecked recaptcha. **You still have to verify the recaptcha on server side** because a bot does not care ...

Add a an invisible input tag with `required=true` attribute just below the `div.g-recaptcha`.

```
<input id='recaptcha_check_empty' required tabindex='-1',
style='width:50px; height:0; opacity:0; pointer-events:none; 
position:absolute; 
bottom:0;'>
```

Enclose both width a `div` with `position=relative;` to point the `bottom:0;` above to the bottom of recaptcha.

Now the Browser asks nicely to fill out this field - pointing to the recapcha.

Now we need the callback:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="recaptchaCallback" ...
```

and

```
function recaptchaCallback() { 
    $('#recaptcha_check_empty').val(1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To check if **google recaptcha v2** is checked or not you can do it by the following code :

```
var checkCaptch = false;
     var verifyCallback = function(response) {
        if (response == "") {
             checkCaptch = false;
         }
         else {
             checkCaptch = true;
         }
     };
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
             if (checkCaptch && grecaptcha.getResponse()!="") {
                  //Write your success code here
             }
         });
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="contact-inner contact-message">
  <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">CAPTCHA</label>
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo 6LfSJmocAAAAAFFMpMKB1CtYNJYDyDswO7GpxRXS ;?>">
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>CAPTCHA</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="contact-inner contact-message">
        <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">CAPTCHA</label>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo GOOGLE_KEY ;?>"></div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

if for some reason you are conditioning a form by hand like me, and required is not working.

First import ReCAPTCHA

```js
import  ReCAPTCHA  from 'react-google-recaptcha'
```

Apply it in your component

```html
<ReCAPTCHA style={{margin: '5px', transform: 'scale(0.8)'}} ref={recaptchaRef} sitekey={recaptchaKey} onChange={updateRecaptcha}/>
```

you can use a `useRef` or just use the `ReCAPTCHA` you've imported, I used `useRef`.

```js
const recaptchaRef = useRef<any>()
```

And now, how do I check if `recaptchaRef` is checked?

```
if (recaptchaRef.current.props.grecaptcha.getResponse().length !== 0) {
    //your condition
}
```

basically, you are saying 'if recaptcha is true, then do this'

this is complete form code that helps you (I'm using typeScipt)

```
const Formid = // yout formid
const FormSpark = `https://submit-form.com/${Formid}`

type FormState =  {
    name: string,
    mail: string,
    message: string
}
const initialState = {
    name: '',
    mail: '',
    message: '',
}

const [wrongmail, setWrongmail] = useState(false)
const [wrongname, setWronname] = useState(false)
const [wrongtext, setWrongtext] = useState(false)
const [alert, setAlert] = useState(false)
const recaptchaRef = useRef<any>()
const recaptchaKey = //your recaptcha public key    const [recaptchaToken, setRecaptchaToken] = useState<string>()
const [formstate, setFormState] = useState<FormState>(initialState)
const submit = async(event: FormEvent) =>{
    event.preventDefault()
    await postSubmission()
}
const updateRecaptcha = (token: string | null)=>{
    setRecaptchaToken(token as string)
}
const {name, mail, message} = formstate
const postSubmission = async() => {
    const payload = {
        ...formstate,
        "g-recaptcha-response": recaptchaToken
    }
    try {
        if (name && mail && message) {
            if (mail.includes('@') && mail.includes('.') && mail.length > 5) {
                if (name.includes(' ') && name.length> 5) {
                    if (message.length > 20) {
                        if (recaptchaRef.current) {
                            if (recaptchaRef.current.props.grecaptcha.getResponse().length !== 0) {
                                console.log('hola')
                                setAlert(true)
                                const result = await axios.post(FormSpark, payload)
                                setFormState(initialState)
                                recaptchaRef.current.reset()
                                if (result) {
                                    setTimeout(() => {
                                        setAlert(false)
                                    },2000)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!name && !(name.length> 5) && !(name.includes(' '))) {
                setWronname(true)
                setTimeout(() => {
                    setWronname(false)
                },3000)
            }
            if (!mail && !mail.includes('@') && !mail.includes('.') && !(mail.length > 5)) {
                setWrongmail(true)
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    setWrongmail(false)
                },3000)
            }
            if (!message && !(message.length > 20)) {
                setWrongtext(true)
                setTimeout(() => {
                    setWrongtext(false)
                },3000)
            }
        }
    } catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}

const updateForm = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    const {id, value} = event.target
    const formKey = id as keyof FormState
    const updatedFormState = {...formstate}
    updatedFormState[formKey] = value
    setFormState(updatedFormState)
}
```