# Google ReCAPTCHA how to make required?

Tags: jquery, html, validation, recaptcha, parsley.js

Does anyone know how to make the "[Google ReCAPTCHA (v2)](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro)" be "required" in a `form`?

I mean no form submission until recaptcha is filled-in?

I use ParsleyJs in my form, but didnt find a way to make it work with `div`s...

Comment: Other solutions not worked for me... This worked- [https://stackoverflow.com/a/28676035/4836581](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28676035/4836581)

Comment: @ZviRedler the solution provided in the link disables or enables the button... it does however let the form be submitted programatically or if user just do F12 and "enable"s the submit button...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to use the reCaptcha verify response call back. Something like this: `<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=reCaptchaCallback&render=explicit'></script>`

```
var RC2KEY = 'sitekey',
    doSubmit = false;

function reCaptchaVerify(response) {
    if (response === document.querySelector('.g-recaptcha-response').value) {
        doSubmit = true;
    }
}

function reCaptchaExpired () {
    /* do something when it expires */
}

function reCaptchaCallback () {
    /* this must be in the global scope for google to get access */
    grecaptcha.render('id', {
        'sitekey': RC2KEY,
        'callback': reCaptchaVerify,
        'expired-callback': reCaptchaExpired
    });
}

document.forms['form-name'].addEventListener('submit',function(e){
    if (doSubmit) {
        /* submit form or do something else */
    }
})
```

Comment: Instead of using "document.querySelector('.g-recaptcha-response').value" you can use "grecaptcha.getResponse()"

Answer (score 3):

For [ParsleyJS](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html) you will to do a little workaround:

1.Add hidden input field, with `data-parsley-required="true"`, `value = ""`, like this:

```
<input id="myField" data-parsley-errors-container="#errorContainer" data-parsley-required="true" value="" type="text" style="display:none;">
```

2.Add error container (just below or under your `g-recaptcha` div):

```
<span id='errorContainer'></span>
```

3.Add this simple function somewhere in your js code:

```
function recaptchaCallback() {
    document.getElementById('myField').value = 'nonEmpty';
}
```

4.Add the attribute `data-callback` with value of custom function:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="***" data-callback="recaptchaCallback"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find another working example here: https://codepen.io/reactionmedia/pen/JVdmbB

For this example I am going to create two HTML elements inside the form:

```
<div id="botvalidator"></div>
<div id="captchaerrors"></div>
```

**botvalidator** will contain the google recaptcha iframe with the "I am not a robot" checkbox inside.
**captchaerrors** will contain errors after checking that user has not clicked on the "I am not a robot" checkbox.

*IMPORTANT: We are using arrive.js library in order to know when google recaptcha is adding a new g-recaptcha-response textarea element in the DOM because prior DOM new node insert validations are no longer valid. This event will happen after recaptcha is loaded into the page for a couple of minutes.*

You can Download arrive.js library from:
https://github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive/

or insert it directly from CDN provider, for example:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/arrive/2.4.1/arrive.min.js

Remember to insert ALL libraries after loading JQUERY library to avoid errors. I am using Jquery 2.2.4 version

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Another important thing is to remember loading recaptcha library in this way, in order to execute onloadCallback function after loading recaptcha and render recaptcha "manually"

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"></script>
```

Here is the code snippet:

```js
var onloadCallback = function() {
        /**
         * If we try to load page to show the congrats message we don't need to load recaptcha.
         */
        if($("#botvalidator").length > 0) {
            grecaptcha.render('botvalidator', {
                'sitekey' : '6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI',
                'callback': cleanErrors
            });
            addCaptchaValidation();
            /**
             * We are going to use arrive library in order to check new google recaptcha
             * element added after the current one is expired and then we will create new attributes for that element.
             * Expires-callback google recaptcha is not working, probably it is executed before element creation.
             * https://github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive/
             */
            $(document).arrive("#g-recaptcha-response", function() {
                // 'this' refers to the newly created element
                addCaptchaValidation();
            });
        }
    };

        /**  We are going to remove all errors from the container. */
    var cleanErrors = function() {
        $("#captchaerrors").empty();
    };
    
    var addCaptchaValidation = function() {
        console.log("Adding captcha validation");
        
        cleanErrors();

        $('#myform').parsley().destroy();

        $('#g-recaptcha-response').attr('required', true);
        // We are going to create a new validator on Parsley
        $('#g-recaptcha-response').attr('data-parsley-captcha-validation', true);
        $('#g-recaptcha-response').attr('data-parsley-error-message', "We know it, but we need you to confirm you are not a robot. Thanks.");
        $('#g-recaptcha-response').attr('data-parsley-errors-container', "#captchaerrors");
    $('#myform').parsley();
    };
    

    /** We are going to add a new Parsley validator, this validation is called from
    #g-recaptcha-response after clicking the submit button*/

    window.Parsley.addValidator('captchaValidation', {

            validateString: function(value) {
                if(debug) console.log("Validating captcha", value);
                if(value.length > 0) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }                    
            },
            messages: {en: 'We know it, but we need you to confirm you are not a robot. Thanks.'}
          });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Parsley and Google Recaptcha Example</h1>
<form id="myform">
  Full name
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" data-parsley-required="true">
  <br/>
<div id="botvalidator"></div>
<div id="captchaerrors"></div><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Form">
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parsley.js/2.8.2/parsley.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/arrive/2.4.1/arrive.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

That's all folks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a rule
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#custom-validation-rules

Then use it in your controller

```
// validation
$this->validate( $request, array(
    'g_recaptcha_response' => ['required', 'string', new Captcha()]
));
```