# How to make Google reCAPTCHA a required field?

Tags: google-api, recaptcha

How can I make Google's `No CAPTCHA reCAPTCHA` a required field?
I mean, I want to check it with HTML or JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have to do is prevent the form submission until you can validate the user response by using the Google reCaptcha verify callback, then, if it passes, allow the form to submit. See this answer: [Google ReCAPTCHA how to make required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612879/google-recaptcha-how-to-make-required/29613089#29613089) and also check the documentation: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#example