# Recaptcha 2.0 verification code placement

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I have an inquiry form and I've already added recaptcha 2.0 into it. Now, I need to add verification code into my form's validation file. The problem is that I don't know how exactly that verification code should look like and where I should put it into my validation file.

Here is a whole validation file code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//global vars

    var enquiryfrm = $("#agt_mail_agent");

    var yourname = $("#agt_mail_name");

    var yournameInfo = $("#span_agt_mail_name");

    var youremail = $("#agt_mail_email");

    var youremailInfo = $("#span_agt_mail_email");

    var frnd_comments = $("#agt_mail_msg");

    var frnd_commentsInfo = $("#span_agt_mail_msg");



    //On blur

    yourname.blur(validate_yourname);

    youremail.blur(validate_youremail);

    frnd_comments.blur(validate_frnd_comments_author);

    //On key press

    yourname.keyup(validate_yourname);

    youremail.keyup(validate_youremail);

    frnd_comments.keyup(validate_frnd_comments_author);



    //On Submitting

    enquiryfrm.submit(function(){

        if(validate_yourname() & validate_youremail() & validate_frnd_comments_author())

        {
            //hideform();
            return true
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    });



    //validation functions

    function validate_yourname()

    {

        if($("#agt_mail_name").val() == '')

        {

            yourname.addClass("error");

            yournameInfo.text("Please Enter Your Name");

            yournameInfo.addClass("message_error2");

            return false;

        }

        else{

            yourname.removeClass("error");

            yournameInfo.text("");

            yournameInfo.removeClass("message_error2");

            return true;

        }

    }

    function validate_youremail()

    {

        var isvalidemailflag = 0;

        if($("#agt_mail_email").val() == '')

        {

            isvalidemailflag = 1;

        }else

        if($("#agt_mail_email").val() != '')

        {

            var a = $("#agt_mail_email").val();

            var filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z]{2,4}$/;

            //if it's valid email

            if(filter.test(a)){

                isvalidemailflag = 0;

            }else{

                isvalidemailflag = 1;    

            }

        }

        if(isvalidemailflag)

        {

            youremail.addClass("error");

            youremailInfo.text("Please Enter valid Email Address");

            youremailInfo.addClass("message_error2");

            return false;

        }else

        {

            youremail.removeClass("error");

            youremailInfo.text("");

            youremailInfo.removeClass("message_error");

            return true;

        }



    }



    function validate_frnd_comments_author()
    {                
        if($("#agt_mail_msg").val() == '')
        {
            frnd_comments.addClass("error");
            frnd_commentsInfo.text("Please Enter Comments");
            frnd_commentsInfo.addClass("message_error2");
            return false;
        }else{
            frnd_comments.removeClass("error");
            frnd_commentsInfo.text("");
            frnd_commentsInfo.removeClass("message_error2");
            return true;
        }

    }    
function reset_email_agent_form()
{
    document.getElementById('agt_mail_name').value = '';
    document.getElementById('agt_mail_email').value = '';
    document.getElementById('agt_mail_phone').value = '';
    document.getElementById('agt_mail_msg').value = '';    
}
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make Google reCAPTCHA a required field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29752659/how-to-make-google-recaptcha-a-required-field)

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is prevent the form submission until you can validate the user response by using the Google reCaptcha verify callback, then, if it passes, allow the form to submit. See this answer: [Google ReCAPTCHA how to make required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612879/google-recaptcha-how-to-make-required/29613089#29613089) and also check the documentation: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#example

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that my form is validated (if all required fields are filled out correctly) from .js file. I know I can't validate recaptcha from .js file. How I can make my form's fields validated from .js file and recaptcha from another file? How I should do that? That .js file is in my first post (the code).