# how to add required rules for reCaptcha?

Tags: jquery, recaptcha, rules

currently my codes are working ok but i wish to make reCaptcha field and required field for used but no sure how to achieve it, here is the js part of my code.

```
$(function() {  
$("#form").validate({    
    rules: {
        name: "required",
        phone: {
        required: true,
        digits: true,
        minlength: 10,
        maxlength: 14
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        address: "required"
    },        
    messages: {
        name: "Enter your full name",
        phone: {
        required: "Phone number is required",
        digits: "This is not a numeric value",
        minlength: "Number is too short",
        maxlength: "Number is too long"
        },
        email: "Please enter a valid email address",
        address: "Address is required"
    },              
      submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

});

and this is the recaptcha div

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="--Site-Key--">
```

how can i make this field required anyone?

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29752659/how-to-make-google-recaptcha-a-required-field/29760366#29760366

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google ReCAPTCHA how to make required?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612879/google-recaptcha-how-to-make-required)