# how to validate google reCaptcha on submit button

Tags: php, joomla3.0, recaptcha

On Joomla 3, I have added the new Google reCaptcha on the form page, but the Google reCaptcha doesn't validate with the submit button. Though reCaptcha is right there on the form page, I can still submit the form without ticking the checkbox. Basically the submit button doesn't validate/link up with the reCaptcha.

As per google reCaptcha direction, I have done the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

And then place the reCaptcha div in the form page where I want to show:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcOrgsTAAAAAEKWXDbi08wBM-V7ELRwpay76OA1"></div>
```

And the submit button code in the following:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="Joomla.submitbutton('payment')"><?php echo JText::_('COM_JKPAYMENT', true); ?></button>
```

So can you tell me, what condition I need to set so that the Form submit is validate with the reCaptcha.

Comment: You have to check if the response came back from google. See this Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612879/google-recaptcha-how-to-make-required/29613089#29613089

Answer (score 0):

You need to call *grecaptcha.getResponse()*.
The id for my submit button is btnSubmit.

```
<script>
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
        if(response.length != 0) //validation successful
           Joomla.submitbutton('payment');
        else
         //validation failed
    });
</script>
```