# Validation of g-recaptcha-response using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I have already implemented reCAPTCHA using Java application at the backend for  verifying captcha response using secret key and  g-recaptcha-response. I was wondering if there is recommended way to do the same using at client side using JavaScript? and How I can keep secret key and response token hidden from bad guys? Also is there any advantage on client side validation over verifying captcha response using the  application backend

Thanks
Nitin

Comment: This answer may help with client side validation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612879/google-recaptcha-how-to-make-required/29613089#29613089