# AJAX form with priority values

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, recaptcha

I want to create form with priority values, first check vlaue of recaptcha if is correct (not spammer) then do process for example:

```
   if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
{
      $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

}
    if(!$captcha)
        {
        echo "enter captcha";

    }

    $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=*******&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

        if($response.success==TRUE){

            $name = $_POST['name'];

            if($name == "hello"){
                echo 'correct';
            }

        else {
                echo 'incorrect';
            }
        }


    if($response.success==false)
    {
        die("spammer!");

    }
```

and HTML code like:

```
      <form id="form" method="POST" action="">

                     <input id="name" name="name" type="text"/>

                 <div class="g-recaptcha-response" data-sitekey="******"></div>

                 <input id="button" type="submit" value="send" />
</form>  

                  <div id="formresult"></div>
```

`<div id="formresult"></div>` is for ajax answer

I wrote some script code but not worked and I prefer ask without paste that code in here. how could I do that?

Comment: You say it didn't work. What exactly is not working?

Comment: `if($response.success==TRUE){` ?? `$response.success` ?

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas ajax doesn't show any result

Comment: `$response.success` should be `$response['success']` or `$response->success` or just `if($response)`

Comment: @devpro oh sure! but how ever I need that ajax code first lol

Comment: u want to use this code in ajax?

Comment: @devpro yeah I want this form doesn't refresh to "form.php" for example, and show reasult in same form page by ajax code

Comment: Hi again, have you solved your problem or not yet? I'm back home so perhaps I can take a look.

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas oh really thanks if you solve my problem :)

Comment: @mahdi Can you paste in pastebin.com or somewhere what is the response of `$response`?

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas here there is some information: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

Comment: See if this helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612879/google-recaptcha-how-to-make-required/29613089#29613089

Comment: @colecmc I saw but when I put my ajax code in "/* submit form or do something else */" noting echo and only page refreshed. today I really confused for this problem!