# Google recaptcha in custom form

Tags: wordpress, forms, recaptcha

I can send the form with or without the box checked.
No idea where to go here.

I have a "custom" form that accepts email addresses.
An earlier uploaded `.csv` file is checked for that specific email address and sends the email address and set of data corresponding with that email address in the `.csv` file.

This all works but I need to add a reCaptcha function. So I wanted to use Googles.

Here is the code (without the check and mail function). The basic form

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="field_name" />
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcYnikUAAAAAMUyMmPRUlnnF-1i3pShj52unsn5"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Versturen" />
</form>
```

The header contains:
`<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>`

Further info:
- The `php` that handles the email and file check is added after the form (also tried before the form but no difference)
- I get warnings saying it can't include `wp-load.php` but if I send the form it will send and deliver.

```
Warning: include(../../../wp-load.php): failed to open stream: File or folder doesn't exist in /home/xxx/wp-content/themes/xxx/template.php on line 39

Warning: include(../../../wp-load.php): failed to open stream: File or folder doesn't exist in /home/xxx/wp-content/themes/xxx/template.php on line 39

Warning: include(): Failed opening '../../../wp-load.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/php') in /home/xxx/wp-content/themes/xxx/template.php on line 39
```

Line 39: 
`include '../../../wp-load.php';`

Any idea why the reCaptcha won't work?

Comment: Hello Interactive, you could add some javascript, to help get your form working. Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612879/google-recaptcha-how-to-make-required/29613089#29613089

Comment: Figured it out. I didn't implemented the verification. Feel really stupid now. Thnx tho'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs verification.....
Because the form is custom I needed to implement the verification.
Form:

```
<div>
    <form action="" method="post" id="FORMID" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="field_name" /><br />
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="==SITEKEY=="></div>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
</div>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=nl'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery("#submit").click(function(e){
                var data_2;
            jQuery.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/THEME/includes/google_captcha.php",
                        data: jQuery('#FORMID').serialize(),
                        async:false,
                        success: function(data) {
                         if(data.nocaptcha==="true") {
                       data_2=1;
                          } else if(data.spam==="true") {
                       data_2=1;
                          } else {
                       data_2=0;
                          }
                        }
                    });
                    if(data_2!=0) {
                      e.preventDefault();
                      if(data_2==1) {
                        alert("Check the captcha box");
                      } else {
                        alert("Please Don't spam");
                      }
                    } else {
                        jQuery("#FORMID").submit
                   }
          });
        </script>
```

`google_captcha.php`

```
<?php
$data;
header('Content-Type: application/json');
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
  $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
}
if(!$captcha){
  $data=array('nocaptcha' => 'true');
  echo json_encode($data);
  exit;
 }
 // calling google recaptcha api.

$response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=KEYSECRET&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
 // validating result.
 if($response.success==false) {
    $data=array('spam' => 'true');
    echo json_encode($data);
 } else {
    $data=array('spam' => 'false');
    echo json_encode($data);
 }
?>
```