# Javascript - google ReCaptcha V2 execute function after successfull validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha

This is my code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var widgetId1;
var onloadCallback = function() {

    widgetId1 = grecaptcha.render('le_captcha', {
      'sitekey' : 'xxx',
      'theme' : 'light'
    });
};


function check(){
    alert(grecaptcha.getResponse(widgetId1));
}

function executeMeAfterSuccessfullValidation(){
    alert('user passed');
}
</script>


<button onclick="check()">check if passed</button>

<div id="le_captcha"></div>
```

I want `executeMeAfterSuccessfullValidation` to be called after the user successfully validate.

There is nothing in their docs how to do that: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display

But I've seen some websites doing it. How?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe they are returning a promise? Try that? Or a callback parameter?

Comment: The callback parameter is executed right after page load. What do you mean by "returning a promise" ?

Comment: This is a promise https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Ok but how could I use it on recaptcha?

Comment: @EduardUnruh Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612879/google-recaptcha-how-to-make-required/29613089#29613089