# google recaptcha V2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here is my html code

```
<form  method="post" action="email-check.php" class="col-lg-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="#####" ></div>
    <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

what jquery code i must to add to  my page to avoid submit form when user not check 
checked box google recaptcha

Comment: `#recaptcha-anchor` element has `aria-checked` attribute that is `false`. When recaptcha is checked, the attribute value is changed to `true`.

Comment: See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28674946/how-to-check-in-js-that-user-has-checked-the-checkbox-in-google-recaptcha). I think it solves your problem.