# How to make button visible when user solves recaptcha

Tags: jquery, checkbox, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I want to design a form but having a trouble about checkbox. After user cliks checkbox, recaptcha will come. When user solves captcha then button will be visible and clickable. Here is my code. How can i make it?
Here is an similar problem of my problem, i read it but could not make it work:
[How to check in js that user has checked the checkbox in Google recaptcha?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28674946/how-to-check-in-js-that-user-has-checked-the-checkbox-in-google-recaptcha)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>reCAPTCHA</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var onloadCallback = function() {
        grecaptcha.render('html_element', {
          'sitekey' : '6LcBb9keAAAAAPo_a4gacC2s0mgufO8K56-NFC5Y'
        });
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="?" method="POST">
      <div id="html_element" class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="recaptchaCallback" data-sitekey="6LcBb9keAAAAAPo_a4gacC2s0mgufO8K56-NFC5Y"></div>
      <br>
      <input disabled type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
        async defer>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

<script>
  function recaptchaCallback() {
    jQuery('#submitBtn').removeAttr('disabled');
};
</script>
```